# Ubuntu Script run a series of script one line by one line automatically

Tags: linux, bash, shell, ubuntu

I am a new Ubuntu user. 
Recently, I try to set up a server on Ubuntu.
I am wondering how to write a automatically script to run a series of script one by one.
For example, I need to install squid first, after that I need to make a copy of config file then modify the file. The following are the steps that I write in the command console. I wonder how to make a script to run that automatically.

```
sudo apt-get install squid -y;
cd /etc/squid3;
sudo cp squid.conf squid.conf.bak;
sudo rm -rf squid.conf;
sudo nano squid.conf
```

Answer (score 2):

Just add a shebang, place everything in a ".sh" file, make the file executable, and run it...

Save this as `test.sh`

```
#!/bin/bash

sudo apt-get install squid -y;
cd /etc/squid3;
sudo cp squid.conf squid.conf.bak;
sudo rm -rf squid.conf;
sudo nano squid.conf
```

Make it executable `chmod +x test.sh`

Run it... `./test.sh`

**To edit the file from a terminal**

Get a terminal on the box where you want the script to live.  Probably you will SSH into it.

Then just `cd` to the path you want the script to live and do the following...

`nano test.sh`  This opens the nano terminal text editor.

Copy the above `test.sh` commands, make sure to get the shebang (`#!/bin/bash`).

Paste the script into the nano editor, you'll need to use ctrl+v or cmd+v.

Hit the key combination of `ctrl + o`, hit the enter key.

Hit the key combination of `ctrl + w`.  This exits nano.  Proceed with the abov instructions.

I suggest you read up on nano so you can get more familiar with its abilities as it can save a lot of time!

Comment: Thanks. I am not familiar with linux. May I know is there any easy way to make a test.sh without user-interface ?  My situation is that I only have a web-based command line interface which do not have import script function. So I wonder if i have to make a test.sh first do it mean that I still have to type them one by one ?

Comment: Use nano, or vim, or any other terminal based text editor.  Then just copy and paste everything into the editor.   I personally recommend nano in your case since you don't sound familiar with linux text editors and vim might... be frustrating.  Check the answer for details....

Answer (score 0):

I have wrote some script for my VPS and this is a example for Squid3

```
#!/bin/bash

function add_user () {
    while true; do
        echo -e "\nInsert a name for the Squid3 user (0=exit): \c"
        read utente
        case "$utente" in
            0)
                echo -e "\nGoodbye $USER!\n"
                exit 0
            ;;
            *\ *)
                echo -e "\nYou can't use spaces in the name!"
                sleep 2
                continue
            ;;
            *)
                break
            ;;
        esac
    done
    if [ ! -e '/etc/squid3/.passwd' ]; then
        sudo htpasswd -c /etc/squid3/.passwd $utente
    else
        sudo htpasswd /etc/squid3/.passwd $utente
    fi
}

function installer () {
    sudo apt-get install squid3 apache2-utils -y
    sudo bash -c "echo 'here
you
must
paste
your
configuration
file' > /etc/squid3/squid.conf"
    sudo service squid3 restart
}

if ! [ "$(sudo which squid3)" ]; then
    installer
    add_user
else
    add_user
fi
```

First run it install squid3 and apache2-utils (for htpasswd) and after make a new user.
If you run it again you can add more users.